# Where can I download ksoap2 3.4.0 jar

Tags: java, android, jar, download, ksoap2

I tried to find ksoap2 3.4.0 jar, I'm looking for this jar since few days.. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: Download from here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/k/Downloadksoap2android252jar.htm

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the version I was looking for. This answer below is good :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out these 2 links:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-base/3.4.0/

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/3.4.0/

Comment: Please refrain from answering off-topic questions.